# How do I specify a starting timestamp in a livestream.com video?

Tags: video, livestream.com

YouTube provides a way to give someone a link to a video, with a specific starting timestamp.

I'd like to do something similar, but with a livestream video.  Here's [a sample livestream video](https://livestream.com/accounts/2689920/events/4249529/videos/95810497).

Comment: Alternatively, may I safely (legally) republish the video on youtube, but skipping over the dead airtime and yada yada at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available for Livestream videos.

However, if you are the producer of the content and want your
viewers to watch a stream starting a specific time, you can create a video
highlight that you can send to them.

Here are instructions on how to do that: [What Is a Highlight and How Do I Create One?](https://help.livestream.com/hc/en-us/articles/219090827-What-Is-a-Highlight-and-How-Do-I-Create-One)

Answer (score 1):

### It is available now. Just tested on a live stream.

Change: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkUH6T7H8OU 
to: 
https://youtu.be/mkUH6T7H8OU?t=3600 
Timestamp counted in seconds. And is counted from the beginning of the video. 
If you wanted to link to a timestamp for 30:05 after the video started, you would set it to: ***?t=1805***

It does count time from the beginning which never changes. So while refreshing the page might change the beginning numbers from ***-1:30:05*** to ***-2:30:05*** indicating the livestream is now 1 hour longer, **30:05** from the start of the video will always be **1805**.
It does require a little math, but it does work.

- 900 = 15 minutes
- 1800 = 30 minutes
- 3600 = 1 hour

*Video linked is just for example purposes, but hilarious to watch.*

Comment: OP asked about livestream.com, not YouTube videos.